# Loki - How do I install just Places folder of Icon Theme?

Tags: release-loki, themes, icons

I downloaded the repo [Super Flat Remix](https://github.com/daniruiz/Super-Flat-Remix) and I'd like to take just one aspect of it -- the 'places' subfolder, which changes the folder icons in the files app.

Do any of you guys know of any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Gnome Icon Theme Specification](https://developer.gnome.org/icon-theme-spec/) lists the option for one icon theme to inherit some properties from another, specifically:

> If an icon name is not found in the current theme, it is searched for in the inherited theme (and recursively in all the inherited themes).

Extract the Super Flat Remix theme to `~/.icons` as per the [instructions](https://github.com/daniruiz/Super-Flat-Remix#installation), and then replace the contents of `~/.icons/Super Flat Remix/index.theme` with:

```
[Icon Theme]
Name=Flat Remix
Comment=An icon theme for Gnome Shell, the set is inspired by the latest flat design trend.
Inherits=elementary
Directories=places/scalable,places/symbolic

[places/scalable]
Size=512
Context=Places
Type=Scalable
MinSize=16
MaxSize=512

[places/symbolic]
Context=Places
Size=16
MinSize=16
MaxSize=512
Type=Scalable
```

By including only references to the icons you want, everything else should be inherited from the vanilla `elementary` icons.

Comment: thank you mike, i thought it would be something like that. However, the issue (perhaps separate issue entirely) iks that I actually had already tried making the folder ~/.icons/Super Flat Remix/ and it wasn't showing up in System Settings > Tweaks.

Comment: HA! Turns out the first time I tried I put the wrong folder into .icons -- it was a folder one level above the one I was supposed to put in (with the same name). It all works now. Perfect! Thanks so much! I've chosen you as the correct answer.